# How to reshape dataframe from 1-D to 2-D, but from the dataframe itself

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I would like to reshape the dataframe itself because I would later like to draw a scatterplot (K-means) using the dataframe itself. The transformation does not seem to happen as the dimension is still 1-D, so what am I doing wrong?

```
print(df['Intensity_per_workout'].ndim)
print(df['Number_of_programs_taken'].ndim)

df["Intensity_per_workout"] = df["Intensity_per_workout"].values.reshape(-1,1)
df["Number_of_programs_taken"] = df["Number_of_programs_taken"].values.reshape(-1,1)


print(df['Intensity_per_workout'].ndim)
print(df['Number_of_programs_taken'].ndim)



km = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
y_pred = km.fit_predict(df[['Intensity_per_workout',
'Number_of_programs_tak]])
print(y_pred)
df["cluster"] = y_pred
print(df.head())
df1 = df[df.cluster==0]
df2 = df[df.cluster==1]
df3 = df[df.cluster==2]
df4 = df[df.cluster==3]
plt.scatter(df1["Intensity_per_workout"], 
df1['Number_of_programs_taken'], color='green')

plt.scatter(df2["Intensity_per_workout"], 
df2['Number_of_programs_taken'], color='red')
plt.scatter(df3["Intensity_per_workout"], 
df3['Number_of_programs_taken'], color='black')
plt.scatter(df4["Intensity_per_workout"], 
df4['Number_of_programs_taken'], color='yellow')
plt.xlabel('Intensity_per_workout')
plt.ylabel('Number_of_programs_taken')
```

Comment: Try `df[['Intensity_per_workout']]`

Comment: are you sure that you actually need to reshape (not clear what you actually trying to reshape anyway)? `plt.scatter(df['Intensity_per_workout'], df['Number_of_programs_taken'])`  will probably work just fine...

Comment: I have edited the post to make you see what I'm trying to get to: I want to be able to plot scatterplot with scaled dataframe columns. As for CJR, I appreciate your help, but it didn't work. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: I still don't see what the problem is. `'Intensity_per_workout'` etc are columns in your dataframe? so you're fine doing KMeans on those. Why do you want to reshape them?

Comment: An alternative way to producing the scatterplot without influencing the original data is also appreciated, but I would prefer the first option. Thank you

Comment: When I try doing KMeans I am getting a reshape error. It is stating that I have a 1-D array and that it needs to be fed a 2-D array

Comment: I want to rescale them before applying K-Means because they are not on same scale. I use MinMaxScaler() and I get the following error: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 5.  4. 22. ...  6. 15.  4.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: `df[['Intensity_per_workout']]` yields a dataframe which is 2d by definition. I don't know how you made it not work.

Comment: `scaler = MinMaxScaler()` `scaler.fit(df[['Intensity_per_workout']])` `scaler.transform(df[['Intensity_per_workout']])`etc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CJR and konstanze's contributions, it was found that I had to use double brackets to issue a 2-D array, without needing to reshape dataframe, like so:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler().scaler.fit(df[['Intensity_per_workout']]) 
scaler.transform(df[['Intensity_per_workout']])
```

Comment: Did you mean `MinMaxScaler().scaler.fit`? There's no dot between `MinMaxScaler()` nnd `scaler` in your code...